# Decrease index by one with each click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created an function that allows me to click next and it increases the index by one.  Now I need to create a function that does the opposite and decrease the index by 1.  I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

```js
var idx = $(this).index();

$('.popup').on('click', '.right-arrow', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var nxt = idx++;
  var nxtMember = $('.member').eq(nxt + 2).find('a').attr('href');
  alert(nxtMember);
});

$('.popup').on('click', '.left-arrow', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var idx = $(this).index(-1);
  var nxt = idx - 1;
  var nxtMember = $('.member').eq(nxt).find('a').attr('href');
  alert(nxtMember);
});
```

Comment: `var idx = $(this).index(-1);` it's in local scope.

Comment: You've defined `var idx = $(this).index();` globally and `var idx = $(this).index(-1);` locally.  You should either use a different variable name, or perhaps you mean to use the global variable?

Comment: `$(this).index(-1)` is meaningless. Did you mean `$(this).index() - 1`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.popup').on('click', '.left-arrow', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var nxt = idx--;
  var nxtMember = $('.member').eq(nxt).find('a').attr('href');
  alert(nxtMember);
});
```